# How to get the ScrollViewer to update it's layout after a child does a RenderTransform?

Tags: .net, wpf, transformation, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` and within it I use the Blend control `PathListBox`, whose children I rotate and scale with a `RenderTransfrom`.

Unfortunately, the `ScrollViewer` sizes to the size of my `Ellispe` (the control that I'm using as my path) and I can't figure out how to get `ScrollViewer's` viewport to include the entire control (all the `PathListBoxItem`s.)

I thought the reason it wouldn't size to the complete size of my PathListBox was because of my `RenderTransform`, but I tried replacing it with a `LayoutTransform` and it still cuts out stuff (not as bad though, but a `LayoutTransform` is not what I need).

My Xaml looks something like this (for the sake of simplicity I left some stuff out):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse ... />
        <ec:PathListBox ...>
            <ec:PathListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ...}"
                            </TransformGroup>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle ... />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ec:PathListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                <ec:LayoutPath SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=ellipse}" ... />
            </ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>    
        </ec:PathListBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a hack for the time being that masks the problem. I'm still looking for a more correct approach to fixing the problem though. :)

I added a transparent Rectangle to the grid and made it's width equal to the size of the Ellipse + the size of (length) PathListBoxItems that were transformed.

The scroll area now allows me to scroll to areas that were previously clipped.

EDIT: I'll mark this as the answer for the time being since it does work. I just don't feel like this is the best solution so I'll be willing to mark another answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

RenderTranforms don't affect the layout. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx):

> A render transform does not regenerate layout size or render size information. Render transforms are typically intended for animating or applying a temporary effect to an element. For example, the element might zoom when focused or moused over, or might jitter on load to draw the eye to that part of the user interface (UI).

What you want is a LayoutTransform. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx):

> In contrast to RenderTransform, LayoutTransform will affect results of layout.

and

> Example scenarios where LayoutTransform would be useful include: rotating elements such as menu components from horizontal to vertical or vice versa, scaling elements (zooming in) on focus, providing editing behavior, etc.

It sounds like you're using the wrong layout element (in addition to using the wrong transform), but it's difficult to tell since you don't actually say what you want to do.  The reason it was still cutting stuff off when you did a LayoutTransform was probably because there wasn't enough space for the items to render completely in the available space.

Edit:

Give the additional information I would suggest using a custom panel type: the "radial" panel.  Examples [here](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/04/simple-radial-panel-for-wpf-and.html) and [here](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/use-radial-panel-in-list-box-for-nested-data/).

Comment: well I did try using a Layout transform and it still clipped stuff :(

Comment: If you can be more specific about what you're trying to do then I can be more specific about how to address your issue.

Comment: Initially the pathlistbox place its items where they're like tangent to the circle. I rotate and translate them so they look as if they're coming out the circle like sun rays. The scrollviewer clips the "rays" and only shows an area that fits the size of the ellispe.

Comment: it almost sounds more like you want a canvas than a grid

Comment: The grid works well. A canvas would require more work to get everything positioned right. And I started this control in Blend and it enclosed everything in a grid.

Comment: oh I didn't notice your edits. when I first started working on this control I did find those sources and implemented a radial panel. I didn't quite get it working how I wanted to and then I discovered Blend already implemented the control I needed with the PathListBox. It's exactly what I need, just it's items were getting cut off when I transformed them.

Comment: Gotcha.  Have you tried  - "find the Orientation property and change the value from “None” to “OrientToPath”. From: http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/

Comment: Yes, my orientation is set to OrientToPath and I set Distribution to Even.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then.  It's hard to help much when I don't have blend.  :-P

Comment: thanks for the help. :) you can use the blend controls if you install the sdk though.